# Yeoman - How to add express server task to Gruntfile.js generated by generator-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, gruntjs, yeoman

New to grunt, I'm trying to add express server to my AngularJS application (generated with Yoeman).

I've modified the following task like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.writeln('Starting web server on port 8080.');
    var server = require('./server.js');
    server.listen(8080);
});
```

and my server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});
```

running the `server task` produce the following output:

```
Running "server" task
Starting web server on port 8080.

Done, without errors.
```

If I nevigate to my localhost on port 8080, I can see the server is offline. it is obvious that the task exits. why? what do I need to add to the Gruntfile in order to get a basic server up and running?

---

**Edit**: I guess I need to add a keepalive option to my task somehow, I just not sure how.

Comment: interesting question. have you tried https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-express ?

Comment: Nope, I've already started working on my app ... I'm trying to integrate a custom server to the already running app

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it as an async task. Do this:

```
grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.writeln('Starting web server on port 8080.');
    var server = require('./server.js');
    server.listen(8080).on('close',this.async());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... however I get the following error 'D:\dev\wamp\www\LPSocial\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\node_modules\tmp\lib\tmp.js:261
  throw err;
        ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
'

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz you have another server active that runs on 8080 - change the port to 8081 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Please check grunt-express at: https://github.com/blai/grunt-express

This plugin will allow you to start an express server using your own express application script.

Note that this server only runs as long as grunt is running. Once grunt's tasks have completed, the web server stops. This behavior can be changed by appending an express-keepalive task at the end of your task list